# Division of binary numbers, confusing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, binary, binary-operations

I am trying my best to divide the following:

> Perform the following computations in binary arithmetic (Show how you perform
> the computations):

[image]

**My attempt:**

[image]

**I watched:**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF_sLkAnI1U
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKemv9u40gc

**Question:**
*What is a more easy way, or approach to perform this, without really getting lost and confused?*

---

EDIT: Due to confusion of the question above, I am simplifying this: **N.B. It's not about straightly calculating it, but, documenting the exact steps how you arrive to that solution.**

It states in the task,

> Perform the following computations in binary arithmetic (Show how you perform
> the computations):

---

According to the solution paper, this is what I see.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand necessarily what is confusing about this.  It works exactly the same in binary as it does in decimal.  Do you get equally confused when dividing in decimal?  Perhaps the numbers are too big for you... rather than dividing by $110000$... recognize that $110000 = 11\cdot 10000$, so divide first by $11$ and then divide the result by $10000$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, please kindly be respectful. Not everyone in this world, can match your level. You see the steps I been attempting to perform, moving stuff around, keeping track of with 1s and 0s, I get confused. So, after days and hours of not grasping this, I thought, I post here. **N.B. It's not about straightly calculating it, but, documenting the exact steps how you arrive to that solution**.

Comment: $1111011$ divided by $11$ will be $101001$ by inspection.  (*think of $1111011$ as $\color{green}{11}\color{blue}{11}0\color{red}{11}$ and recognize each colored group as being $11$*).  Dividing by an additional $10000$ moves the decimal point over four points giving an answer of $10.1001$

Comment: @JMoravitz, that's not the main issue here. `(Show how you perform the computations)`, how would you document the exact steps and calculation for arriving to that solution. I trying to do that, and learn that, step-wise and systematically. So regardless of what I attempt to divide in binary, I know the exact approach to begin from.

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of extra steps. As JMoravitz said it's not that different from doing it in decimal. When you divide in decimal, for example, 987654321 by 12345, do you begin by trying dividing 9 by 12345, 98 by 12345, 987 by 12345, 9876 by 12345, ...?

Comment: Again, long division works exactly like it does in decimal.  Looking at what you have written, you have gone from the line 11110-0 to the line $11110\color{red}{11}$ minus 110000 having dropped *two additional* bits down.  You skipped one.  You were going by increasing the number of bits one at a time until then, correctly so.  Why did you suddenly increase by two bits?  Had you increased by only one bit you would have seen 111101 - 110000 and should have seen that this was indeed positive, equaling 001101, and continuing with the long division process as normal.

Comment: @JMoravitz, hence why I decided to post here. Because, I am a bit new to long division in binary. I thought, I could ask here to get some answer or at least, someone would show me. Because, at this point I cannot do more --- while I try to do it, I get a bit confused because, of the moving and appending of 0s and so forth. You can make fun of me, how much you want.

Comment: Believe it or not, I am trying to be helpful... I have no opinion of your skills and you as a person and am responding as though I am devoid of emotion.  I am stating facts and am pointing out mistakes, not as an effort to "make fun of you" or to "be disrespectful"... but because it is important to do so in order to make the mistakes be known so that you can avoid them in the future.  We point out mistakes so you can grow.  If you can not stomach having your mistakes pointed out to you, then you need to mature more.

Comment: @JMoravitz, *I don't understand necessarily what is confusing about this. It works exactly the same in binary as it does in decimal. Do you get equally confused when dividing in decimal?*

Comment: That is a legitimate question.  Do you or do you not understand how to perform long division in decimal?  If you answer yes, then the conversation goes in one direction to try to identify what specifically went wrong as you tried to do long division in binary.  If you answer no, then the conversation goes in another direction and attempts to teach long division in more detail (regardless of base).  The steps performed (*drop down next digit or bit, attempt to subtract, check if positive number, write number of times you can subtract and it remain nonnegative, repeat*) are the same in binary

Comment: @JMoravitz, I am not good with performing *Long division* this is a honest response. Now, I have an upcoming written exam, because, I failed the previous one, mainly because of not being able to perform nor document the exact steps to the arrived solution/answer.

Comment: See the solution. I want to know, how to perform the steps, to get the exact same solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loosely phrased, the long division algorithm is performed as follows:

First, write the numbers with the number you are dividing by on the left and the number you are dividing into on the right, the number you are dividing into inside of a portion of a box for organizational sake.

```
       _________
110000 | 1111011
```

Now, pull the first digit down of the number you are dividing into.  Check to see if the number you are dividing by is less than or equal to that digit you pulled down.  If it is, then subtract the number you are dividing by out of that digit you have pulled down as many times as you can so as to have the result still be non-negative.  In binary, this can only be once or not at all, but in decimal it could be several times.  Keep track of the result of the subtraction as well.

Write the number of times you subtracted your number in the corresponding position above the bar at the top, writing zero instead if you were not able to subtract the number.

Continue the process by using the result of the subtraction of the previous iteration (*or the same digits/bits as were available the previous step in the case that no subtraction occurred*) and append **the next single additional digit/bit** from the original number being divided into.

> This is where you appear to have confused yourself in your work pictured.  You suddenly one of the times increased the number of digits twice, having skipped a step, when you went from the line with 11110 to the next with line 1111011 having not had a line with 111101 between.

Again, repeat the process, check if the number you are dividing by is less than or equal, writing the number of times it can be subtracted away at the top, and keeping the result of that subtraction available for the next line to use.

The process ends when all digits of the number you are dividing into have been used up and the result of the subtraction is zero.  This may mean that you need to continue past where the digits would normally have ended, at which point you should include the decimal point and append only as many zeroes after the decimal point as you need and drop those down.

The result after the first several iterations should look something like this:

```
         0000010.1~~~
       __________
110000 | 1111011.   \
         1      .    \
        -0      .     \
        __             |
         11     .      |
         -0     .      | --  For what its worth, all of this could be
        ___            |  skipped since we know we need at least as
         111    .      |  many digits as what we are dividing by
          -0    .      |
        ____           |
         1111   .      |
           -0   .     /
        _____        /
         11110  .   /
            -0  .  /
        ______
         111101 .   <------ You skipped this step
        -110000 .
        _______
         0011011.
              -0.
        ________
           110110
          -110000
        _________
           000110
```

If we were to complete the process we get as a final picture... this:

```
         0000010.1001
       ______________
110000 | 1111011.0000    <---- We added the decimal point and enough zeroes as we needed to complete
         1      .  
        -0      .  
        __         
         11     .  
         -0     .  
        ___        
         111    .  
          -0    .  
        ____       
         1111   .  
           -0   .  
        _____      
         11110  .  
            -0  .  
        ______
         111101 .   
        -110000 .
        _______
         0011011.
              -0.
        ________
           11011 0    <--- this empty space doesn't mean anything, it is just there to let numbers line up correctly
          -11000 0        If writing by hand, the decimal point would have not used up an entire column
        _________
           00011 0
                -0
              ____
              11 00
                 -0    <---- 1100 is not larger than 110000 so we subtract nothing, writing a zero at the top in this position
              _____
              11 000   <---- we then pull down an extra digit
                  -0
              ______
              11 0000
             -11 0000  <---- what we are dividing by is less than or equal, so we subtract it from the running remainder
              _______
                    0   <---- equal to zero so we are done, so write the 1 at the top in this position
```

This is, again, annoying to do with such large numbers and such wide spaces between doing things.  Graph paper where you can keep things perfectly lined up and your vision doesn't get blurred is helpful... but it can be better to break this up into larger meta-steps.

A much better thing to here is to recognize $110000$ is equal to $11\cdot 10000$, and recognize that $1111011\div 110000$ is equal to $(1111011\div 11)\div 10000$

Doing the same as above but dividing by $11$ instead gives more regular interaction and smaller numbers to deal with at each step:

```
     0101001
   __________
11 | 1111011.
     1      .
    -0
    __
     11     .
    -11     .
     __
      01    .
      -0    .
      __
       11   .
      -11   .
      ___
       000  .
        -0  .
        __
         01 .
         -0 .
         __
          11.
         -11.
          __
           0.
```

After this, we divide by $10000$, but dividing by a number of this form is well known to be equivalent to just moving the decimal place an appropriate number of spaces.

Comment: How did you get `0000010.1~~~`? Thanks BTW for detailed answer.

Comment: *"After this, we divide by 10000"*, you mean after long division is performed?

Comment: @AlixBlaine "*How did you get `0000010.1~~~`?*"  After the first attempt to subtract we were unable to, so we wrote a $0$.  That is where the first zero came from.  After the second attempt to subtract, we were unable to, so we wrote another $0$.  That is where the second zero came from.  This continues until our sixth attempt to subtract and we were able to do so once.  That is where the first $1$ came from in the sixth position.  We continue the process, and I did so two more steps but intentionally did not fully complete, marking where I left off with the `~` chars to imply more follows.

Comment: @AlixBlaine "*'After this we divide by 10000', you mean after long division is performed?*"  After division by $11$ of whatever style you choose.  As alluded to in the comment chain above, long division is not strictly necessary here.

Comment: Can you show the rest? 
`_________
000110`

Comment: @AlixBlaine drop a zero, can't subtract since 1100 is smaller than 110000... drop another zero but can't subtract since 11000 is smaller than 110000... drop another zero and finally we can subtract and 110000-110000 is equal to zero and so we are done.  A lot of this is incredibly tedious and this is only usually used when it is difficult to organize our thoughts.  When you are more comfortable with it, it is customary to skip steps.

Comment: Can you please complete it, so that, I see exactly how it must be done? Please.

Comment: I do not find a final image to be useful in and by itself.  I think watching the table be built in motion is far more useful, and a video seeing it *in person* is necessary if learning to do this the first time.  I intentionally stopped midway through so as to attempt to show the thought process.  To complete the process, you do as I said in my previous comment which should have been enough information already to complete.  I'll add it, but know that this goes against my intention and makes the post appear to be an extra page in length as a result which hurts readability.

Comment: @AlixBlaine again, I dislike this being as lengthy and wordy as it is... I do not think it should take an entire page to perform a single division for numbers of this size.  You can do like the pictured "solution" in blue where long strings of steps are skipped and rather than dropping down a single digit at a time we drop down exactly as many digits as we need (*and no more*) at each step to get to the next available number which is larger than (*or equal to*) what we are dividing by.  That skips all of these "subtract zero" lines, making this take a fraction the total space.

Comment: JMoravitz, due to this statement: **(Show how you perform the computations)** I am asking, my interpretation is that, it means show the whole process. It said so on the written exam I did, which I failed.

Comment: You yourself asked in your post "*What is a more easy way, or approach to perform this, without really getting lost and confused?*"  I gave you several ways, each of which can be documented to your hearts content, and each of which should satisfy even the strictest grader.  I stand by saying the most easy and effective way is to first divide by $11$ and then divide later by $10000$.

Comment: **JMoravitz**, it is true I did. And I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
         0000010 

       |-------- 
110000 | 1111011
         110000
         ------
         0011011
          000000
          ------
           11011 : Remainder
```

In the above **long division** example, where each of the numbers is in base 2 format, first, you are dividing the SIX digit number 111101 by the divisor of 110000, to yield a quotient of 1.

Then, you compute the product of 1 $\times$ 110000, and place it below the six digit portion of the dividend 111101.

Then, you perform the subtraction, and your new *partial dividend*  is 011011.

Then, you *rinse and repeat*.  The steps exactly analogize to the steps that you would take in a standard base 10 long division problem.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I follow along here. Can you show me in paper form? I have seen the solution, but, I want to know how to achieve it systematically step-wise.

Comment: According to the solution paper, the answer is: **10,1001**

Comment: @AlixBlaine I have added an explanation of the steps involved.  Does my explanation make sense to you?  If not, please leave a further question.  Also, either I have made an analytical/arithmetic mistake, or I haven't.  If you can see an analytical/arithmetic mistake in my work, please also leave a comment, following this answer.

Comment: @AlixBlaine As a sanity check, convert each of the following base 2 numbers, into base 10 numbers: the dividend, the divisor, the quotient, and the remainder.  Then check whether (in base 10), the following arithmetic is accurate: $$[~\text{quotient} ~\times~ \text{divisor} ~] + ~\text{remainder} = \text{dividend}.$$

Comment: See the solution. I want to know, how to perform the steps, to get the exact same solution.